# Find the sum of $ (1 \times 1!) + (2 \times 2!) + (3 \times 3!) + \cdots+ (50\times50!)$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

What will be the sum of following series

$$ (1 \times 1!) + (2 \times 2!) + (3 \times 3!) + \cdots+ (50\times50!)$$

Is there any general solution for $n$ terms?

I have tried writing nth term and then summing up but I was unable to write the nth term only. So now I have no idea how to do this question.

Comment: Particular case of: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/737402/321264.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
(n+1)!-n!=[(n+1)-1]\cdot n!=n \cdot n!, \quad n=0,1,2,\cdots,
$$ getting a *telescoping sum* here.

Comment: How did we get ...=[(n+1)-n]n!

Comment: @geekyme Because $(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot n!$...

Comment: I am still unable to understand because expanding [(n+1)-n]n! would give (n+1)! - nn!. But l.h.s. is (n+1)! - n!

Comment: @geekyme indeed there was a typo in Olivier's answer. See the edit

Comment: Thanks I was also thinking that there was some mistake but I am relatively new so I was not sure . :-)

Comment: @b00nheT Thank you very much!

Comment: @OlivierOloa you are welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

You have $$\sum_{k=1}^n kk! = (n+1)!-1$$
Proof via induction, with the induction step:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} kk! = \sum_{k=1}^n kk!  + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+1)!-1 + (n+1)(n+1)!
=(1+n+1)(n+1)! - 1 = (n+2)!-1$$