# Combinatorial argument for the identity $\sum_{r = 0}^n r \cdot r! = (n + 1)! - 1$

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

We can rewrite the sum as:

\begin{align}
\sum_{r = 0}^n r \cdot r!
&= \sum_{r = 0}^n (r+1-1) \cdot r! \\
&= \sum_{r = 0}^n [(r+1)!-r!]
\end{align}
This latter sum telescopes, leaving
$$\sum_{r = 0}^n [(r+1)!-r!] = (n+1)! -1.$$

Looking at the results I was curious if there is some way it correlates to arranging $13$ objects in $13$ places without repetition and removing one case. If so, what would be the combinatorial argument for the summation?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737402/combinatorial-proof-of-sum-k-0n-k-cdot-k-n1-1?rq=1

Comment: Thank you :) must've missed it